# How to fix mongo db issue in production mode in Heroku?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku

I just tried to push my application on Heroku - it is made of a node.js server and a react app in the client.
The server is linked to Atlas Mongo DB.

Everything works fine in local development.

But in production mode, after pushing my project (Heroku deploys the project without any problem), when I run the production url, it crashes and `heroku logs --tail` tells the following:
`Error: Cannot find module '../wireprotocol/constants'at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/sdam/topology_description.js:5:24)`

I tried to uninstall / reinstall node_modules as well and the mongoose package but it does not help...

Any idea of how to fix the bug ?

Comment: I had this application https://codeconnect.app
which is running on heroku on Node server with MongoDB Atlas DB and its working fine
If you can share more details, we can help

Comment: hi @ShubhamTripathi, thx for the comment ! I'd like to give you more details but unfortunately it's the only info I have... it tells me that there is problem with `wireprotocol/constants`, but the file does exist...

Comment: which version of mongoose are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Mongoose version 5.4.18. Also, in your local, you can clone from heroku in a new folder and try to run there, may be you ave installed some dependency and forget to add --save because of which its working on local but not on heroku so, you can try once